# Blocking request based on location

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using Spring Zuul application to route incoming requests to appropriate service , however i want to restrict access to few services based on the location of the incoming request. 
Say for example Service A can be accessed from anywhere in the world.
Service B can be accessed only from India.

I want to know if this is possible in Spring/Java.Any other approach is also welcome.

Comment: You should be able to write a custom zuul filter that reads the remote address

Comment: But then again if there's a chance of a  proxy request.